# One .pot per domain in Pyramid i18n

Tags: python, pyramid, python-babel

in a Pyramid application we have some sections and templates where we use different translation domains (appart from the default domain).

Currently, if we run `python setup.py extract_messages`, all translation strings from all domains are generated in one single .pot file. How can we do to make Babel generate separate .pot files for each translation domain?

Comment: After looking at Babel's [`extract.py`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/babel/blob/master/babel/messages/extract.py), I get the feeling it's simply not possible (no match for 'domain' in the whole file). Which is... astonishing, to say the least.